# How to print instance of a List inside stream builder of flutter

Tags: list, flutter, printing

Hi I am using StreamBuilder to check my data...and usually I am able to print snapshot.data but when I am doing that.. I always get instance of LoginRespon ... where LoginRespon is a List.. here is the image... [image]

is there a way to print the value of status ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Try something like this:

```
List data = snapshot.data
// Convert it to a List
LoginRespon resp = data[0]

//then use like this
print(resp.status)
```

I hope this helps, i haven't tested this though.

Comment: wait, I will try now

Comment: I get error that say ```type 'List<LoginRespon>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'```... is there another way instead of ```Map data = snapshot.data```

Comment: Replace Map data with List data

Comment: @uyhaW check the new update.. the old one was json object just to help you get the idea